# Searching for names in mySQL that contain slashes from mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql

In my users table I have a first and last name field.

I also have a search for user by last name but when there is a user like L'Orange searching for

- lor
- LOr
- L'O
- l'o

does not work while

- L\'O does (which makes sense but not something a user would think of)

So, how can my query account for that?  Right now in my query I have

```
OR (CONCAT(`lName`, ', ', `fName`) LIKE '$term')
```

I'd like the search lo or l'o to work (I think)  Is there any reason the search should require the '?

Comment: Did you use addslashes() to filter $term? If yes, they should already be adding the needed slashes, if not, then that's what you're missing (and btw, you have an SQL injection waiting to happen there).
By the way, don't use addslashes(), at least use mysql_real_escape_string(), since addslashes() doesn't clean up everything.

Comment: No I didn't but that would make sense...I am using mysql_real_escape_string() - not just addslashes() afterall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you take the incoming search term and apply mysql_real_escape_string to it?

```
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($term);
```

then

```
OR (CONCAT(`lName`, ', ', `fName`) LIKE '$term')
```

should work.  The user will have to search for l'o or L'O, but that should work.

Comment: Looks like you stole from the first comment above but I'll take this as the answer since it does the trick.